# Javascript unexpected result for adding two input box values

Tags: javascript

I was trying to add two text box fields values in Java script. Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function addFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("firstInput").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("secondInput").value;
    var sum=x+y;
    alert('Sum is:'+sum);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="firstInput"><br/>
<input type="text" id="secondInput"><br/>

<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addFunction()">

</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the result will be sum of two field values but it is not
I entered 2 in first text field and 3 in second text field out put is

```
Sum is:23
```

Then only for testing I have added below code in addFunction()

```
var a = 0.0343;
var b = 0.11;
var x = a + b;
alert(x);
```

**output is**

```
0.144299999999999998
```

What's going on. Can someone explain me why I am getting these two peculiar output?

Comment: What does `myFunction()` do?

Comment: where is myFunction()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: my bad. It is not related to this question. sorry. I removed it from code now.

Comment: you can use `x.toFixed(2)` 2 is quantity of decimals you want

Answer (score 1):

The `value` of `input` elements are strings. `"2" + "3" == "23"`

To get your expected output you can do this:

```
function addFunction() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstInput").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondInput").value);
    var sum=x+y;
    alert('Sum is:'+sum);
}
```

Regarding the second question, you can read more here: [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The values that come back from the input fields are strings. When you add two strings, they append. So "2" + "3" is the string "23".

You can convert the strings to integers using parseInt. As in:

```
var sum = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
```

Comment: @Rahul Can you please accept my answer if it solved your problem? I did reply first and I could use the rep.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parseInt()` to get exact output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function addFunction() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstInput").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondInput").value);
    var sum=x+y;
    alert('Sum is:'+sum);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="firstInput"><br/>
<input type="text" id="secondInput" onchange="myFunction()"><br/>

<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addFunction()">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because its taking your input values as characters instead of actual numbers. When you set variables a and b in your second example you're setting them to number values. If you want numbert values change your add function to

```
function addFunction() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstInput").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondInput").value);
    var sum=x+y;
    alert('Sum is:'+sum);
}
```

There you convert all text values to int then add in the function

Answer (score 0):

**Typecasting**

Inputs and textareas contain string values. This is why your sum mashes the values side by side.  That's how string concatenation works.

```
'foo' + 'bar' //foobar
'1' + '2' //12
1 + 2 //3
```

You need to typecast them to number in order for it to work.  You can use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) to do this.  Number only finds the numeric values and runs much faster.  parseInt [is slower](https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls) but it can remove character values and convert hexadecimal.

```
Number('1') + Number('2') //3
```

**Handing Floats**

For your Trailing number issue.

```
 0.0343 + 0.11 //0.144299999999999998
```

This occurs because floating numbers are sorted using fractions.  Fractions like 2/3rds don't convert well back into their decimal form.  You can read the long explanation [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/binary/).  Anyways, use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to format this correctly.

```
Math.PI //3.141592653589793
Math.PI.toFixed(2) //3.14
```